# Why can't set the value type property of prototype via the this pointer

Tags: javascript

I have the following Javascipt code.

```
var Person = function(){};
Person.prototype.age = 0;
Person.prototype.setAge = function(age) {
    this.age = age;
};

var jack = new Person();
console.log(jack.age); // #1
jack.setAge(25);  // Why not this function assign the value to Person.prototype.age.
console.log(jack.age); // #2
console.log(jack);
```

After running the code, I got the output as below.

```
0
25
Person {age: 25, age: 0, setAge: function}
age: 25
__proto__: Object
    age: 0
    constructor: function (){}
    setAge: function (age) {
    __proto__: Object
```

At the statement labeled #1, the **age** property is found in the prototype of the **jack** instance. It is reasonable to print the **0**.

At the statement **jack.setAge(25);**, when execute the code **this.age = age;**, it seems a new property is added to the **jack** instance. I'm confused why not the function **jack.setAge(25);** assign the value to **Person.prototype.age**?

Thanks,

Jeffrey

Comment: Worked for me http://jsfiddle.net/ykrK2/

Comment: Check out [how `this` works](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this)

Comment: If you had two people and the function was setting `Person.prototype.age` then you would always end up with the code saying they were both the last set age

Comment: @Paul, right. That's also what I mean in my answer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What happens is:

1. Intepreter looks for a `setAge` function in `jack` object.
2. It's not there, so it looks one level up in a prototype chain. It's there.
3. Intepreter invokes `setAge` with `jack` bound to this. So `this.age` in a `setAge` relates to `jack`, not `jack.prototype`.  Thus jack.age = 25.

If you want to modify `age` property of a Person, you can call:

```
 Person.prototype.setAge(7);
```

(now `this` will be bound to `Person.prototype`).

Comment: Thank you for your answer. It seems the behaviors are different for the get and set operator. My code labeled #1 is a get operator, the interpreter will looks for the prototype chain. The code in function setAge is a set operator. It only looks for the properties owned by the instance pointed by this. Is this the javascript standard?

Comment: @Jeffrey - both `.age` and `.setAge()` are properties of the `jack` instance. One of them is a number (instance of Number type) and the other is a function (instance of Function type). Difference is that `age` is a so-called "own property" (it means that it's defined in `jack` object directly, there's no need to do a prototype-chain lookup), while `setAge()` is a property of the jack's prototype. Do not confuse them with getters and setters - those are defined in ECMAScript 5, but their syntax differ and in your case, you're not using neither.

Answer (score 0):

> I'm confused why not the function jack.setAge(25); assign the value
>   to Person.prototype.age?

It does not make sense to assign the value to `Person.prototype.age` because this property is to be inherited. If this statement assigns the value to `Person.prototype.age`, all objects inheriting from this will be affected. That's why browsers implement `this` in this case to refers to an instance object (jack) ,not the `Person.prototype` which is the reason for

> when execute the code this.age = age;, it seems a new property is
>   added to the jack instance.